How to divide 2d matrix according to specified position
I have a feature map that needs to be divied with another 2d constant, the feature map has shape [H, W, ...] , the 2d constant has shape [H, W] , however when I use np.divide it says these two tensor can not be broadcast to a common shape:
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(4, 3 ,3)
b = np.random.rand(4, 3)

c = np.divide(a, b, where=b > 0)

as the numpy broadcast rules say b will be broadcast to shape [1, 4, 3] instead of [4, 3, 1] , thus I can't do this operation with boradcast.
I would like to divide my feature map with that constant tensor where the constant is not 0 to avoid zero-div error, what should I do ?

Expand the dimensions of b to (4,3,1)

Personally, I would probably write:
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(3)  # Set seed for reproducibility
a = np.random.rand(4, 3 ,3)
b = np.random.normal(size=(4, 3))  # Use `normal` to produce more `where` misses

b = b[..., np.newaxis]
c = np.where(b > 0, a / b, a)

However, to stay closer to your code, one could write equivalently:
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(3)  # Set seed for reproducibility
a = np.random.rand(4, 3 ,3)
b = np.random.normal(size=(4, 3))  # Use `normal` to produce more `where` misses

c = a.copy()
np.divide(a, b[..., np.newaxis], where=b[..., np.newaxis] > 0, out=c)

Notable changes to your code:

Manually add a dimension to b so that its shape is compatible with a (i.e. expand the 4×3 array to a 4×3×1 array).
Provide an explicit output array out=c with np.divide(), because its where argument only produces meaningful results in connection with a given out array (see documentation of np.divide()).
Use a copy of a as the output array, meaning that in places where b <= 0, the given a value will be the result instead (which is what you want, if I read your question correctly).

In either case, the result will be contained in c.

Yes it's easy to forget you need an out when using a where like this.

The problem is not the whereargument. The problem is, that you have undefined operations. np.divide performs the divide operation element wise. As noted in the documentation:

Divisor array. If x1.shape != x2.shape, they must be broadcastable to a common shape (which becomes the shape of the output).

So the question is: what exactly are you trying to do? Your question is poorly defined. Think of a matrix as a grid with an intersection at each entry. A 2d array is like a plane, while a 3d array is like a cube. You can slice 2d planes from the array and append them back together or you may simply have a poorly defined problem.
Edit: You can read about broadcasting rules here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html
